# How can I debug server side rendering blazor code in a component?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, blazor-server-side

I'm building a server-side rendering blazor app

In Program.cs I have

```
builder
    .Services
    .AddRazorComponents()
    .AddInteractiveServerComponents();
```

and

```
app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
    .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();
```

In a component I have something like this, which is not working, and I would like to debug this code, with breakpoints, but I don't find a way to debug it

```
@using  System.Globalization
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime
@inject NavigationManager Nav

<select class="form-control" @onchange="ChangeLanguage">
    @foreach (var language in supportedLanguages)
    {
        <option value="@language">@language.DisplayName</option>
    }
</select>

@code
{
    CultureInfo[] supportedLanguages = new[]
    {
        new CultureInfo("en-US"),
        new CultureInfo("pt-PT"),
        new CultureInfo("fr-FR"),
    };

    private async Task ChangeLanguage(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        var culture = e.Value?.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine("culture is " + culture);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(culture))
        {
            await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("BlazorCulture.setCulture", culture);
        }
    }
}
```